# For Loop not looping through storage keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I have a simple `For` loop that is supposed to loop through all keys in sessionStorage, but it's like its not looping at all.
This is the loop:

```
function loadCheck() {
     console.log(sessionStorage.key(1));
     for (var i = 0; i <= sessionStorage; i++) {
        console.log(sessionStorage.key(i));
     };
};
```

The first console.log outside of the loop works but then nothing is logged from the loop. I saw a similar question like this here and tried their solution but it did not work. The whole point of this loop is to retrieve the keys and push them into an array. I am currently using JSON-serialized objects as values, if that helps.

Comment: `i <= sessionStorage` will never be true since `sessionStorage` cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: oh my i forgot to add .length. Thank you for pointing this out!